# Form redirection on configuration PHP page

Tags: php, forms

I have a completely functional Form that sends mail as it should and all BUT for some reason, when I (try to) submit my message, instead of showing the success or error alert under the form, it opens the `sendmail.php` page with the messages, without any CSS... It's been 4 days and I'm going crazy. I'm sure it's actually a stupid typo or something but I can't find it, please help.

[Screen of the "Success/Alert" display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35qoC.png)

Here's my sendmail.php:

```
<?php
$sendto = 'my@email.com';

$subject = 'Message de votre site';

$errormessage = 'Ah, vous avez oublié quelques informations. Réessayez ?&nbsp;';

$thanks = "Merci pour votre message ! On vous répond aussi vite que possible.&nbsp;";

$honeypot = "Vous êtes tombé dans le piège ! Si vous êtes humain.e, recommencez !&nbsp;";

$emptyname =  'Quel est votre nom ?&nbsp;';
$emptyemail = 'Quelle est votre adresse mail ?&nbsp;';
$emptymessage = 'Et votre message ?&nbsp;';

$alertname =  'Utilisez uniquement un alphabet standard.&nbsp;';
$alertemail = 'Entrez ce format de mail : <i>name@example.com</i>.&nbsp;';
$alertmessage = "Vérifiez que vous n 'avez utilisé aucun caractère spécial.&nbsp;";

$alert = '';
$pass = 0;

function clean_var($variable) {
    $variable = strip_tags(stripslashes(trim(rtrim($variable))));
  return $variable;
}

if ( empty($_REQUEST['last']) ) {

  if ( empty($_REQUEST['name']) ) {
    $pass = 1;
    $alert .= "<li>" . $emptyname . "</li>";
    $alert .= "<script>jQuery(\"#name\").addClass(\"error\");</script>";
  } elseif ( preg_match( "/[][{}()*+?.\\^$|]/", $_REQUEST['name'] ) ) {
    $pass = 1;
    $alert .= "<li>" . $alertname . "</li>";
  }
  if ( empty($_REQUEST['email']) ) {
    $pass = 1;
    $alert .= "<li>" . $emptyemail . "</li>";
    $alert .= "<script>jQuery(\"#email\").addClass(\"error\");</script>";
  } elseif ( !preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/", $_REQUEST['email']) ) {
    $pass = 1;
    $alert .= "<li>" . $alertemail . "</li>";
  }
  if ( empty($_REQUEST['message']) ) {
    $pass = 1;
    $alert .= "<li>" . $emptymessage . "</li>";
    $alert .= "<script>jQuery(\"#message\").addClass(\"error\");</script>";
  } elseif ( preg_match( "/[][{}()*+?\\^$|]/", $_REQUEST['message'] ) ) {
    $pass = 1;
    $alert .= "<li>" . $alertmessage . "</li>";
  }

  if ( $pass==1 ) {

  echo "<script>$(\".result\").toggle();$(\".result\").toggle().hide(\"fast\").show(\"fast\"); </script>";
  echo "<script>$(\".result .alert\").addClass('alert-danger').removeClass('alert-success'); </script>";
  echo $errormessage;
  echo $alert;

  } elseif (isset($_REQUEST['message'])) {

    $message = "From: " . clean_var($_REQUEST['name']) . "\n";
    $message .= "Email: " . clean_var($_REQUEST['email']) . "\n";
    $message .= "Message: \n" . clean_var($_REQUEST['message']);
    $header = 'From:'. clean_var($_REQUEST['email']);

    mail($sendto, $subject, $message, $header);
    echo "<script>$(\".result\").toggle();$(\".result\").toggle().hide(\"fast\").show(\"fast\");$('#contactForm')[0].reset();</script>";
    echo "<script>$(\".result .alert\").addClass('alert-success').removeClass('alert-danger'); </script>";
    echo $thanks;
    echo "<script>jQuery(\"#name\").removeClass(\"error\");jQuery(\"#email\").removeClass(\"error\");jQuery(\"#message\").removeClass(\"error\");</script>";
    echo "<script>$(\".result .alert\").delay(4000).hide(\"fast\");</script>";
    die();

    echo "<br/><br/>" . $message;

    }

} else {
    echo "<script>$(\".result\").toggle();$(\".result\").toggle().hide(\"fast\").show(\"fast\");</script>";
    echo $honeypot;
}
?>
```

And HTML:

```
<form class="form-inline flowuplabels" role="form" method="post" autocomplete="off" id="contactForm" action="js/sendmail.php">
    <div class="form-group fl_wrap">
        <label class="fl_label" for="name">Nom :</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name" class="form-control fl_input" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group fl_wrap">
        <label class="fl_label" for="email">Email :</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email" class="form-control fl_input" required>
    </div>
    <span class="form-group fl_wrap honeypot">
        <label class="fl_label" for="last">Honeypot:</label>
        <input type="text" name="last" value="" id="last" class="form-control fl_input">
    </span>
    <div class="form-group fl_wrap">
        <label class="fl_label" for="message">Message :</label>
        <textarea type="text" name="message" value="" id="message" class="materialize-textarea" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" value="Send" id="submit" class="btn btn-block">Envoyer</button>
    </div>
    <div id="form-alert" class="form-group">
        <div class="result">
            <div class="alert"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

As some asked. The HTML is on the index page and the `sendmail.php` is an independent page.
And this is where the success/alert message is supposed to appear :

[Form in website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7DjQ.jpg)

Comment: Email clients almost never play nicely with css unless it is written inline. Most email clients use very OLD browser code to show the email

Comment: Your form's action is `action="js/sendmail.php"` and that file doesn't seem to load any styles

Comment: It doesn't suppose to need it. The success/alert message is supposed to been displayed under my form, not on another page and certainly not on the configuration page itself. It looks like it is the target instead of the "process" and I don't understand why...

Comment: Are those two pieces of code on the same page `sendmail.php`? How/why is that supposed to display under your form? What target exactly? What "configuration page"?

Comment: Nope, the HTML is from the index.html page and the sendmail is an independent page, as I always do. And the success/alert is supposed to display under the "Send" button as a green text if success or orange in case of error/missing item.

Comment: Feels like this is missing some crucial information (or the form/sending is done totally wrong). Is Javascript involved in sending the form? Do you use a framework or something?

Comment: In the sending? Nothing more than what I shared here. 
The only Javascript involved are Materialize and OwlCarousel which doesn't have "sending mails" functions. 

And the form works, I mean my client can receive emails for their website but this particular thing doesn't work. That's so frustrating...

Comment: Sending the mails works because your `sendmail.php` actually sends the mail. But it doesn't load any styles or javascript and I can't think of any way the alerts and all would be shown _under_ the form. You're submitting to a totally different/new page. Only if those were on the _same_ page, form first, then your PHP code to handle the submission/errors.

Comment: I've done this several times and the form's action never acted as a targeted page. If you read the HTML, there is a div below the sending button where the success/alert should appear and it does appear each time I write such codes.